# Flume Twitter Streaming Issue

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume, cloudera-cdh, flume-twitter

I'm using **Flume 1.6.0-cdh5.9.1** to stream Tweets using Twitter source.

The configuration file is below:

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, cloudera

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/tweets/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 600

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 1000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

For the Cloudera .jar dependency, I've built `flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` with Maven using below dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- For the Twitter API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hadoop Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
        <artifactId>flume-ng-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
        <artifactId>flume-ng-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, when I run the Flume Agent, it starts successfully, connects to Twitter, but halts after the last line (**Receiving status stream**):

```
2017-02-08 21:55:12,556 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[initializing]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Establishing connection.
2017-02-08 21:55:46,474 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO -    twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Connection established.
2017-02-08 21:55:46,474 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] Receiving status stream.
```

After the last line nothing happens. It doesn't terminate, doesn't stream anything. I had a look at the HDFS location and nothing is created there.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the configuration `TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords`

Twitter Source will work fine and will continuously pull Tweets as long as it finds data in the Firehose. I tried with some other popular recent keyword and it worked just perfectly fine.